# Envío de ficheros desde Java usando Spring

Tags: java, spring, email

Estoy usando una instancia de JavaMailSender para enviar correos electrónicos con unos pdf adjuntados, el problema es que no consigo adjuntar los mismos de esta manera.

Mi método de envío es:

```
public void sendMailConjuntoStreams(String to, String subject, String text,List<InputStream> streams) {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper helper;
        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(text);

           //trabajar los streams

            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Tengo que pasarle InputStream ya que es información leída desde base de datos.

Podría crear unos ficheros de tipo File y escribirle el contenido de los stream, el problema es que de esa manera no podría poner el título correspondiente de los ficheros a enviar, por ejemplo, si el fichero se llama Lista Pacientes 2, no podría referenciar ese título(salvo que el Stream guardase de alguna manera el título, cosa que desconozco).

Necesito saber como generar un file adecuado para adjuntarlo, ya que si creo los mensajes a través de los Streams no los añade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La solución es la siguiente:

```
//creamos un adjunto con el stream de datos
ByteArrayDataSource attachment = new ByteArrayDataSource(myStream, "application/pdf");
//lo añadimos al correo a enviar
helper.addAttachment("nombreFichero.pdf", attachment);
```

Esto lo puedes hacer para cada elemento que quieras adjuntar.

Comment: Ha funcionado, muchas gracias!